# output is missing information

Tags: xml, powershell

I have the script which reads the xml file and then pings the sites listed in the xml file and output goes to a text file. Which works great except it only displays the last site it ping instead of all the sites.
xml file:

```
<Servers>
    <Server id="1">
        <name>server1</name>
        <cfusion>www.cnn.com</cfusion>
        <dotnet>www.msn.com</dotnet>
    </Server>
    <Server id="2">
        <name>server2</name>
        <cfusion>www.yahoo.com</cfusion>
        <dotnet>www.google.com</dotnet>
    </Server>
    <Server id="3">
        <name>server3</name>
        <cfusion>www.wwe.com</cfusion>
        <dotnet>www.nfl.com</dotnet>
    </Server>
</Servers>
```

script:

```
[xml]$servers = Get-Content c:\cfusion.xml
$collection = $()

foreach($server in $servers.Servers.Server)  {
    $status = @{ "Cold Fusion" = $server.cfusion; "Dot Net" = $server.dotnet; "Server Name" = $server.name; }

    if (Test-Connection $server.name -Count 1) {
        $status["Status"] = "Online"
    } else {
        $status["Status"] = "Offline"
    }

    if (Test-Connection $server.cfusion -Count 1) {
        $status["Cold Fusion"] = "Up"
    } else {
        $status["Cold Fusion"] = "Down"
    }

    if (Test-Connection $server.dotnet -Count 1) {
        $status["Dot net"] = "Up"
    } else {
        $status["Dot Net"] = "Down"
    }

    New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverstatus |
        Format-table -Property "Server Name", "Status", "Cold Fusion", "Dot Net" -AutoSize |
        Out-File c:servstatus.txt
}

$collection
```

Comment: With proper indentation you can clearly see you overwrite the file at each iteration of `foreach`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script has some errors that may come from formatting/copy/paste. It will probably work as intended if you use the `-Append` parameter on `Out-File`.

Comment: Would you mind marking the answer as "accepted" then, so other users don't see this as an unanswered question and investigate?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
out-file c:servstatus.txt
```

To:

```
out-file c:servstatus.txt -Append
```